# Generate many promo codes

Tags: expresso-store, expresso

because we're not able to setup promo codes to different products with Expresso 1.6.5 like you can with 2.x with discounts. We thought to use 200 promo codes with a limited use of 1.

The questions is, is it a problem to enter 200 codes to expresso?
Can this be generated, via our database or with a different tool, which i don't know right now? Do we have to delete this promo codes after use by ourself, or get they deleted when they get used, via expresso store?

Would be great to know, how you would handle this with the 1.6. version

Thanks

Peter

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in Store 1.x by simply adding rows to the `exp_store_promo_codes` table. You can look at existing rows in the table to see the format.

Basically you just need to enter a `promo_code`, set `enabled` to `y`, and set the `use_limit` to `1`.

In Store 2, this table is named `exp_store_discounts`.

You can use a tool such as phpMyAdmin to access the database, or do it programatically from an EE extension.

Comment: As you explained, it work for me.
But is it also planned to generate a set of custom codes and export this as list for a print company? :-)

Comment: How do you mean? You can generate a set of custom codes in Excel, then upload them as a CSV using phpMyAdmin.